# Dots in a <li> not aligning properly

Tags: css, drupal, menu, html-lists

I made a ul > li for job vacancy, but the dots/bullets are acting really wierd. I think something in my code is doing this or I overlooked something. Any help is greatly appreciated.  CSS code for the page:

```
.vacatures{
        width: 80%;
        margin: 0 auto; 
        text-align: center;

        h2{
            font-size: 36px;
            color: #0066ff;
        }

        h3{
            font-size: 32px;
            color: #0066ff;
            padding-bottom: 10px;
        }

        ul{
            padding-bottom: 15px;
        }

        li{
            padding-top: 10px;
        }

        a{
            text-decoration: none;
            color: inherit;
            display: block;
            margin-top: 5px;
            margin-bottom: 20px;
        }

        p{
            font-size: 18px;
            font-weight: normal;
        }
    }
```

HTML :

```
<div class="vacatures">
</div>
<div>
  <h3>Functie omschrijving :</h3>
  <ul>
    <li>omschrijving 1</li>
    <li>omschrijving 2</li>
    <li>omschrijving 3</li>
    <li>omschrijving 4</li>
  </ul>
</div>
<div>
  <div>Vacature pdf</div>
  <div>
    <span class="file file--mime-application-pdf file--application-pdf"><a href="http://localhost/mlndemo/sites/default/files/2017-02/voorbeeld_sollicitatiebrief_0.pdf" type="application/pdf; length=420819">voorbeeld_sollicitatiebrief.pdf</a></span>
  </div>
</div>
<div id="block-tweedevacature">

  <div>
    <h3>Functie omschrijving :</h3>
    <ul>
      <li>omschrijving 1</li>
      <li>omschrijving 2</li>
      <li>omschrijving 3</li>
      <li>omschrijving 4</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div>
    <div>Vacature pdf</div>
    <div>
      <span class="file file--mime-application-pdf file--application-pdf"><a href="http://localhost/mlndemo/sites/default/files/2017-02/voorbeeld_sollicitatiebrief_1.pdf" type="application/pdf; length=420819">voorbeeld_sollicitatiebrief.pdf</a></span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

And an image for easy visualization 
[image]
intended :

[image]

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, your question should contain a Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example, [here's how](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Please add relevant markup and you just might have an MCVE. I'm guessing that's not all the CSS either based on the screenshot.

Comment: Also, it would be nice to know what you want it to look like. What is the intended outcome?

Comment: Include html please?

Comment: Included html and intended outcome. HTML might be little wierd because im working with Drupal and its not really easy to copy that html in here. Thanks for any effort :)

Comment: Something is missing, [this is what you're code is producing](https://jsfiddle.net/j3krgzt4/).

Comment: Do you want the heading and list to be on the left or right? And what exactly is the purpose/intent of centering the text? What is the expected result of centering? If you remove `text-align: center;` from `.vacatures` you'll get what you have in your second image.

Comment: Are you using SASS or LESS? I see that you have nested selectors, is that a typo? `h2`, `h3` etc. are inside of `.vacatures`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Setting a width on the `<ul>` combined with centering it will fix it. This way, you'll center the entire list. I'm guessing the text inside it should be aligned left as well.

```
ul {
   width: 50%;
   margin: 0 auto;
   text-align: left;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

At the top of your html you have

```
<div class="vacatures">
</div>
```

which is not applying that class to anything other than that empty `div`, so all of that stuff in the CSS saying withing the class `"vacatures"` is not actually applying to that.

The second set of `<ul>` and such have a `div` that actually surrounds them but that is a different class, `"block-tweedevacature"`, with which we see no CSS for.